# Help me figure this out please

Tags: riddle

[image]

Help me figure this out please thank y’all

Comment: Please provide the source of this puzzle.

Comment: The answer is: "A cutie pie"

Answer (score 4):

The actual answer is:

> You are a cutie pie (you are acute tea pie)

The two answers given are:

> jokes/sarcastic answers.